# storing state of main proccess in electron

Tags: electron

I am pretty newbies in the electron. I have a serverside project wrote with Express js. so I can communicate with my server side and in electron app, I can work with IPC fine. but my question is where to store states of my main .js entry. so I can use them everywhere. in react for example we have states and props and redux for state management. I searched everywhere but not found a proper way for this.I also found [electron-redux-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-electron-store) .but my real challenge is storing my states in somewhere

Comment: You can not direct use of main process values into render process, alternative is that store your value in file, like use of `electron-store` or localStore.

Comment: @MayankVadiya is localStore is safe enough for keeping token inside it?

Comment: Yes, because you don't have any other way